# How to add Java Object(containing both String and an Image/Bitmap variable) to Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an Android Project using Android Studio.
I have a Model Class named Contact.java which contains 3 variables.
Bitmap mImage, String mAddress, String mPhoneNumber.

I want to store the Contact.java in the Firebase Database and retrieve it at runtime. How to store image and string together in the Firebase so that while retrieving I get the complete object?

For individual purposes I have been using

1. FirebaseDatabase() for retrieving Strings from realtime Database which are stored as key/value pairs in the database.
2. FirebaseStorage() for retrieving Images stored in Storage folder which is then converted to Bitmap and displayed in the ImageView.

I have been fairly successful at this following the documentation.

Now I have a CardView displayed in RecyclerView which contains an image and 2 strings. I need to save and retrieve them together from the Database.

```
public class ContactUsDetails {

    int mImage;
    String mAddress;
    String mPhoneNumber;

    public ContactUsDetails(int image, String address, String phoneNumber) {
        mImage = image;
        mAddress = address;
        mPhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return mImage;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return mAddress;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return mPhoneNumber;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        mImage = image;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        mAddress = address;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        mPhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

I would like to retrieve/store the object from/to Firebase with all 3 variables at the time to display.

Comment: I think you need to find a way to serialize your object so that you can store it somewhere else, for the string objects you can do this right away, the only thing that would take some time to figure out is to serialize the image.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do that? It would be really helpful

Comment: your object has to implement the interface Serializable, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/serialization-in-java/ here is a guide